# Your internal load balancer must have a private subnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to create an internal NLB on AWS to two EC2 instances in two AZs/subnets.

**Configuration:** 1 VPC, two AZs , 2 private and 2 public subnets:

| AZ | eu-central-1a | eu-central-1b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **public subnet** | public 1 | public 2 |
| **private subnet** | private 1A | private 2A |

The EC2 instances are located in the private subnets.

Under Mappings/eu-central-1a I can select *public 1* or *private 1A*.
Under Mappings/eu-central-1b there's only *public 2* and the error message:

```
Your internal load balancer must have a private subnet. 
You can update the subnet’s route table in the VPC Console
```

The private networks and their route tables look identical. Not sure, what else needs to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I used AWS CLI meanwhile. That solved the problem.

```
# aws elbv2 create-load-balancer --type network --name my-load-balancer --subnets subnet-07.......9528 subnet-0a..........5170 --scheme internal
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue, remove the internet gateway from the route table of the private subnets if they exist there.